# How to fetch data for a collection of models using withRelated?

Tags: bookshelf.js

I have two models:

```js
const Post = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'post',
  tags: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany(Tag)
  }
});

const Tag = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'tag'
});
```

I want to get tags for a collection of `Post`.

I have tried:

```js
const Tags = new Bookshelf.Collection([
    Post.forge({
      id: 1
    }),
    Post.forge({
      id: 2
    })
  ])
  .fetch({
    withRelated: [
      'tags'
    ]
  })
  .then((collection) => {
    console.log('collection', collection.toJSON());
  });
```

That gives an error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: ER_BAD_TABLE_ERROR: Unknown table 'undefined'

I am assuming this error is because `Bookshelf.Collection` does not recognise that the first parameter is a list of models. However, the [documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#section-Collection) indicates that it is an expected input:

```js
new Collection([models], [options])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```js
PostModel
  .query('where', 'id', 'in', [1])
  .fetchAll({
    withRelated: [
      'badges'
    ]
  })
  .call('toJSON');
```

It results in a single query:

```sql
select
  `badge`.*,
  `badge_post`.`post_id` as `_pivot_post_id`,
  `badge_post`.`badge_id` as `_pivot_badge_id`
from
  `badge`
inner join
  `badge_post` on `badge_post`.`badge_id` = `badge`.`id`
where
  `badge_post`.`post_id` in (?, ?, ?)
```